# How to add button to MBProgressHUD, relative to text label?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, mbprogresshud

I want to add a custom cancel button to `MBProgressHUD`, and I want it to be just right of text label. But `MBProgresHUD` is drawn by overriding `drawRect` method, so, while I can add button as subview to HUD, i don't know how large text label will be so I can position my button properly.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is possible directly using `MBProgressHUD`. Not without rewriting much of it.

One option could be to just add your own button as a subview of the view you are adding the HUD to that would just close the HUD or cancel the action.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)]; // made up coords here
// set button stuff here
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

You will need to set the button actions, background or image (for look and feel), then add it to your view. Basically 2 views to achieve what you need. HUD and button. Probably a lot easier than rewriting `MBProgressHUD` to allow buttons.